# Getting "node has no member" error in GCC (c99) for basic trie structure

Tags: c, compilation, structure, trie

I'm trying to implement a basic trie structure in plain old C, and I'm getting a "node has no member" error upon compilation.

Here is my structure definition:

```
typedef struct node {
    bool word;
    struct node *alpharray[26];
} node;
```

My attempts to initialize some nodes are as follows:

```
node *root = malloc(sizeof(node));
node *nptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
nptr = root;
```

The above code uses "iterator" as the pointer that will cycle through the given trie structure as it's being created. Here's how that works:

```
while (ch != '\n' && !feof(fp))
{
    //get the array index value for the current character (ch)
    //getCharNum() returns an int 0-25 corresponding to a slot for a node's alpharray
    int char_num = getCharNum(ch);

    //if a character has not been put in the given slot yet, make a new node and point    
    if (nptr->alpharray[char_num] == NULL)
    {
        node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        nptr->alpharray[char_num] = newnode;
        nptr = newnode;
    }

    //otherwise, move the main pointer to the next node in the chain of nodes
    else
    {
        nptr = nptr->alpharray[char_num];
    }

    //get the next character
    fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
}
```

The error I get when compiling repeats each time I try to access and/or change any given node attribute. I have also tried the *node.alpharray notation, which as I understand is the equivalent to the above because node will be dereferenced.

I know it's probably something basic I'm overlooking, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Ideas?

Here is the compiler output:

```
gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror   -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
dictionary.c:30:15: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token
dictionary.c: In function 'load':
dictionary.c:74:21: error: 'node' has no member named 'alpharray'
dictionary.c:77:21: error: 'node' has no member named 'alpharray'
dictionary.c:84:28: error: 'node' has no member named 'alpharray'
dictionary.c:71:17: error: variable 'char_num' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
dictionary.c:93:16: error: 'node' has no member named 'word'
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make: *** [dictionary.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't y ou use (*node.alpharray) instead of *node.alpharray?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand...the *node._attribute_ notation required parens?

Comment: I think the equivalent of x-> is (*x).y and not *x.y , however it's not a solution of your problem.

Comment: Please post the exact text of the compile errors.

Comment: I have now added the compiler output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to initialise the pointers in the array. Try:

```
struct node {
    bool word;
    struct node *alpharray[26];
};

struct node *node_new(void)
{ 
struct node * ret;
unsigned uu;

ret = malloc (sizeof *ret);
if (!ret) return ret;

ret->word = false;
for (uu = 0; uu < 26 ; uu++) {
   ret->alpharray[uu] = NULL;
   }
return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
struct node *root , *nptr;
root = node_new();

for (nptr=root; (ch = fgetc( fp)) != EOF; ) {
     if (ch == '\n') break;
        //get the array index value for the current character (ch)
    //getCharNum() returns an int 0-25 corresponding to a slot for a node's alpharray
    int char_num = getCharNum(ch);

    //if a character has not been put in the given slot yet, make a new node and point    
    if (nptr->alpharray[char_num] == NULL)
        {
        nptr->alpharray[char_num] = node_new();
        }

    nptr = nptr->alpharray[char_num];
    }

}
```

Comment: This solved it! Thanks. I don't know why I was trying to initialize the pointer that starts by pointing at the root. I fixed that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize your node as :

```
node *nptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You create space for the node itself, but not for each of the pointers in

```
struct node *alpharray[26];
```

Since alpharray will be NULL you cannot use it to get an element of it directly. You have to malloc for those elements too.

Comment: I tried an alternate version where I created an initNode() function that did precisely this, but the GCC errors were exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'alpharray' should be declared as:

```
struct node** alpharray[26];
```

because in the line:

```
nptr->alpharray[char_num] = newnode;
```

you ares assigning pointer to a structure (which is illegal).
Your node declaration should be:

```
typedef struct node {
bool word;
struct node** alpharray[26];
} node;
```

When compiler sees your (original) declaration of 'alpharray' it cannot figure out
the size of each element in an array (because the type is not yet fully defined).
That is why it cannot work any other way than with a array of pointers (what you did is an array of 'struct node', not an array of pointers to 'struct node' - what you should do).